# How to send simulated data from a device to an Azure IoT Edge device

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have worked with sending data using a c# code to send simulated data from a device to an IoT Hub, but I am not able to find documentation on how to do the same i.e send data to an on premise IoT Edge device.

Any guidancewould be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use an IoT Edge Device as a gateway? Can you please provide more detail on the scenario you are trying to enable?

Comment: Transparent Gateway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway

Downstream devices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-device

Answer (score 2):

Once you set up IoT Edge as a transparent gateway(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway); and update your connection string used in your C# code to append "GatewayHostName="; your c# code should work and messages will route to Edge Hub and then IoT Hub.